# 'QGIS Processing Executor'_Issue: "sqlite3_open ... unable to open database file"

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, geopackage

Trying to run a self built-in QGIS-model (*.model3) using the followoing 'QGIS Processing Executor' (`qgis_process`) command in the command line does not work.

```
C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.24.1\apps\Qt5\bin>qgis_process run model:Model
--distance_units=meters --area_units=m2 --ellipsoid=EPSG:7019 --native:buffer_1:result='C:/zz_QGIS_Test_SHPs/result.shp'
```

The above written `QGIS Processing Executor` command is based by following the steps as described in the following picture (see also this [link](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Enhancement-Proposals/issues/200))

[image: this attached graphic-1]

By doing so, the further issue appears:

> "...ERROR 4: sqlite3_open('C:/zz_QGIS_Test_SHPs/result.shp'.gpkg)
> failed: unable to open database file..."

[image: this attached graphic-2]

Interesting is though, when the same `QGIS Processing Executor` command is executed with a "temporary layer" (=> `"TEMPORARY_OUTPUT"` instead of a file i.e.: `"result.shp"`) the `qgis_process` command seems to run fine:

[image: this attached graphic-3]

However, I have no idea where the temporary layer is then stored in my PC.

Any help with the above mentioned issue and where are this type of temporary layers stored in the PC?

`QGIS Processing Executor` *is an included QGIS-tool which allows to run Processing algorithms and models (built-in or provided by plugins) directly from the command line without starting QGIS Desktop itself.*

Comment: Given QGIS is mainly used by non-programmers, you might get better answers on [gis.se]. People there will be more familiar with e.g. where QGIS stores its temporary layers.

Comment: Also asked here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/431751/qgis-processing-executor-issue-sqlite3-open-unable-to-open-database-file